# Choosing the right MySQL connection for PHP

Tags: php, mysql

There seem to be a lot of choices for MySQL connection from PHP. I guess they all offer different feature sets. I just want to run a simple query, and so I'm attracted to the simplicity of mysql_connect(). Is this OK or are there any considerations I'm missing

Thhanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to run a simple query, there really is no difference. If you're working on something bigger, use mysqli or PDO instead so you can use it's features. Especially prepared statements is something you really want to use.

I would just forget about the old mysql-library. Mysqli is not harder to use, but it's a big improvement.

Comment: Dealing with prepared statements/results in mysqli can be a pain, esp. in situations where you want to convert the result set to an assoc array. I only recently began using PDO, but I find it easier all around.

Comment: Thanks for all your responses. Right now simplicity is paramount. it's nice to confirm I can go that route and plan a new learning curve at a more appropriate time. Thanks all for your commnts. I appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

Use `mysqli` instead. It has the same simplicity and it is the improved version of `mysql_connect`

See documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect.php).

Answer (score 1):

Even if you are dealing with a single query or a very simple project, use [PDO](http://it.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).
It's how DB stuff it's done nowadays and will likely be done in the future. I think that learning the legacy libraries (`mysql`, `mysqli`) is not a good deal right now. The learning curve is quite the same, and with PDO you have a basis for doing anything you want (e.g. changing DBMS).

And, even if you choose to use the legacy, DBMS-bound libraries, please don't use `mysql`, and do use prepared statements (both `mysqli` and `PDO` have them). Don't do stuff like:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'");
```

Comment: Mysqli is not a legacy library, as far as I know. Only mysql is.

Comment: Not formally declared legacy, I find it a 'legacy' of the past because it is DBMS-bound, whereas we're all moving to DBMS-agnostic libraries.